# Is there a way to inject/swap extensions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, extension-methods, mixins

I have a [few extensions methods](https://gist.github.com/2053553) I use with my asp.net web forms to manage grid view row formatting.

Basically, they act as a kind of "service" to my code behind classes:

```
    protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = e.Row;
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            decimal amount = Decimal.Parse(row.GetCellText("Spend"));
            string currency = row.GetCellText("Currency");
            row.SetCellText("Spend", amount.ToCurrency(currency));
            row.SetCellText("Rate", amount.ToCurrency(currency));
            row.ChangeCellText("Leads", c => c.ToNumber());
        }
    }
```

Unlike an instance of a class, they do not have an interface to be used with a DI container.

Is there any way to obtain the functionality of swappable extensions?

Answer (score 3):

Not at execution time, no - after all, they're just bound as static method calls.

If you *want* to be able to swap them out, you might want to consider *putting* them in interfaces instead...

If you're happy to swap them out at *compile*-time, just change your using directives.

Answer (score 2):

Static class is a cross-cutting concern. You can do DI with static class, if you extract its implementation into non-static class. Then you can assign concrete implementation to your static class field.

Well, my C# is better, then my English...

```
//abstraction
interface IStringExtensions
{
    bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string input);
    bool IsNullOrEmpty(string input);
}

//implementation
class StringExtensionsImplementation : IStringExtensions
{
    public bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string input)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input);
    }

    public bool IsNullOrEmpty(string input)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(input);
    }
}

//extension class
static class StringExtensions
{
    //default implementation
    private static IStringExtensions _implementation = new StringExtensionsImplementation();

    //implementation injectable!
    public static void SetImplementation(IStringExtensions implementation)
    {
        if (implementation == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("implementation");

        _implementation = implementation;
    }

    //extension methods
    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string input)
    {
        return _implementation.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input);
    }

    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string input)
    {
        return _implementation.IsNullOrEmpty(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 this kid of reminds me of the so called [provider pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx)